# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't report tests that throws exceptions (JUnit 5 Jupiter)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 @TestFactory that generates a stream of test cases for a class, and when I run it, IntelliJ tells me that all tests pass. However, when I rerun the tests in Netbeans, I can see that some tests actually failed due to exceptions. The number of "passed tests" is the same, but it looks like any failed tests simply disappears in IntelliJ instead of being reported as errors.

A suspicious thing is that the tests seems to finish with exit code 255.

In the images below you can see how IntelliJ only reports the passed tests (22 307) while NetBeans reports both passed (22 307) and failed (4).

**IntelliJ IDEA:**

[image]

**Netbeans**

[image]

I am running JUnit version 5.0.0-M3 and IntelliJ IDEA version 2016.3.5.

**Edit 2017-03-10:** So far I have concluded that the tests are running since I can put a breakpoint just before the exception is thrown and step through how JUnit catches it. Everything looks correct stepping through the JUnit code as far as I can tell, so I have no idea why IntelliJ doesn't pick it up. If I run the `surefire:test` goal manually, I can see all the failures in the generated .xml-files.

Comment: Show us the code?

Comment: @Emil Forslund intelliJ also says *All Test Passed*. Can you share the 1. intelliJ version used, 2. How do you execute tests in both the cases?(just to make sure the tests failing are even executed in intelliJ are not, which you can debug as well) and 3. code around which this is reproducible if the first two conditions are not resulting in any such discrepancies.

Comment: 1. IntelliJ version: 2016.3.5, Build #IC-163.13906.18
2. Tests are executed by right-clicking on the test file and selecting "Run All".
3. I have tried to setup a separate Maven project with Surefire and annotate my test factories with the @TestFactory-annotation in the same way, but in that project it works and I can see the errors.

When I run the tests manually using mvn surefire:test, the errors are reported in the log. They are not reported to the IntelliJ UI though.

Comment: Okey, I have identified the line that throws the exception by using NetBeans. When I put a breakpoint just before that in IntelliJ and step forward I can see that the exception is in fact thrown, so the tested code is executed. It is just that it isn't reported to the test tool for some reason.

Comment: The code spans thousands of lines so it is not very practical to post it. I have tried recreating the bug in a smaller project, but then the exceptions are being reported as failures.

Comment: If you'll manage to reproduce it in the isolated project, please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).